# Are there any nouns with irregular plurals in Spanish?

Tags: plurales, formas-irregulares, sustantivos

In English, some nouns have regular plural forms ending in -s or -es and fewer are irregular. Fish in the plural is still fish while child becomes children.

In Spanish, nearly all nouns are regular, adding -s or -es. The rule is even simpler than in English (-es is for words that end in consonants and accented vowels other than *é*, s for all others).  Also, words that end in *z* change the *z* to *c* in the plural to retain a pleasing sound in all regional accents.

There are some words borrowed from other languages that have irregular plurals.  In Mexico, the weekly markets are called *tianguis* (singular: *tianguis* plural: *tianguis*) after the Nahuatl word for the same weekly markets (often in the exact same places). *Tianguis* has been a common Spanish word since around A.D. 1520 but it still seems like a piece of traditional pre-hispanic Mexico.

Are there any native or fully absorbed Spanish nouns with irregular plurals?

Comment: https://www.rae.es/dpd/plural

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find [here](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/?key=plural) the complete reference guide for plurals in Spanish by RAE. In that document you can read that there are some differences from the general rules, which aren't as simple as you described but are quite closed.

For example some words coming from other languages can have the same word for singular as for plural:

```
(from Latin) El currículum vitae  --> Los currículum vitae
(from French) El crómlech --> Los crómlech
```

Also, the stressed syllable doesn't change in plurals, but there are 3 exceptions that have different stressed syllable in singular than in plural:

1. Régimen (**Ré**-gi-men) -->Regímenes (Re-**gí**-me-nes)
2. Espécimen (Es-**pé**-ci-men) -->Especímenes(Es-pe-**cí**-me-nes)
3. Carácter (Ca-**rác**-ter) -->Caracteres(Ca-rac-**te**-res)

Comment: Excellent answer.  I almost voted this question to be closed as a list question.  This answer, I believe, summarizes things well.  +1

Comment: Specially in the north of Mexico they add 's' even if it isn't necessary. For example the use of "gentes" instead of just gente.

Comment: Family names are irregular too, hm? I was surprised on my first reading of Harry Potter to find "los Dursley".

Comment: @rezpeitia There are plenty of reasons to pluralize *gente*, though and it gets used a lot across the Spanish speaking world: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gente%2C+gentes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgente%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgentes%3B%2Cc0   You would **never** say "las gente"

Answer (score 8):

There is one entire class of nouns in Spanish which are all regular plurals of the type similar to English "sheep" and "fish" except instead of the singular also being the plural, the plural is also the singular.

There is a class of Spanish compound nouns formed by joining a verb with a plural noun. They are all masculine and always the same form is used for both singular and plural despite all ending in `-s` or `-es`.

In fact they are such a particular favourite of mine that I have been collecting them for years and [I created a special place in Wiktionary to gather them into a category](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aSpanish_verb_plus_plural_noun_compounds).

It ranges from really common ones like [*cumpleaños*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cumplea%C3%B1os) to ones I've never heard before like *[tumbaburros](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tumbaburros)*.

(There are probably other regular plurals, too, but I can't think of any just yet.)

Comment: Nice list! You can add "mataburros" and "lustrabotas" (although it's the same as "limpiabotas") to it.

Comment: Indeed, these names follow the rule of the point "f" in the RAE link I provided, which is: All the words ending in S or X, whose stressed syllable isn't the last one of the word, have the same word for both singular and plural. e.g. Crisis, Tórax...

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina I will. Also it's a wiki so anybody can add to it at any time, you don't even have to log in.

Comment: @Javi: Ah I had never realized that was a reason behind words of this kind. Very interesting!

Comment: Also, not all of them are masculine. For example "buscavidas" and "rompecorazones" are both f. and m. as

Comment: @Javi exactly, hence «parasol» (lo que para el sol) --> «parasoles» even though it's the pattern of verb-noun, because now we have conditions under which we would expect an -es to be added.  It's only going to ever happen in the few cases where the noun is singular in that construction (which is rare, but not unheard of)

Answer (score 0):

Plurals ain't easier in spanish. Adding to Javi's answer there are other caveats to look for, like the ones ended in `z`:

```
lápiz --> lápices
pez --> peces
```

here the `z` get's changed into `c` then add `-es`. Some others have no plurals form since the word is already plural, ex. `gente` has no `gentes`, since `gente` is another plural of `persona` appart `personas`.

There is also the thing about imported words into spanish that pretty much don't have a rule to follow, and they change according to the pronunciation and/or previous rules.

Comment: The bit about z->ces is actually a general rule (not specific to plurals), "z" always changes to "c" before "e" and "i". Eg: "caza" -> "cacería". "paz" -> "pacífico".

Comment: BTW, "gentes" is not very usual, but it exists. http://gramatikus.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/%C2%BFgente-o-gentes/

Comment: But nobody mentioned that my example is *particular* to plurals, just something to take into account when using them. And in my country if you use `gentes` you are labeled as overcorrected and with a lack of knowledge of the spanish (I'm just saying from personal experience, not representing all the spanish speakers).

Answer (score 0):

Many borrrowed words ending in an "l" or "r" form their plural by adding just "s". Also, compound nouns containing a plural noun are invariably singular or plural.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the previous answers are very good. Just for the sake of completion, I would like to add that chemical elements usually DO NOT have a plural, e.g. "calcio", "flúor", ... are always in singular.

Answer (score -1):

The noun 'bistec' (derived from, and meaning the same as, English 'beefsteak') has a plural that LOOKS regular in orthography: 'bisteces'. However, the pronunciation has an odd change. The singular ends in the /k/ sound which changes to the /s/ sound (or /th/ sound in Spain) in the plural.

Comment: I'm surprised that Spanish doesn't use the orthographic change _bistec_ -> ___bisteques___.

Comment: Actually, the plural of "bistec" is "bistecs".

Answer (score -1):

Among the languages I know, Spanish has the easiest plurals ever! Just a bunch of exceptions.... All the other Romance languages (Italian, French, Portuguese, Catalan) have more irregularities as far as plurals are concerned. Not to mention Rumanian with its many irregular and sometimes unpredictable plurals!
I've always thought Spanish is similar to artificial languages, such as Esperanto in this regard.... 
I would hardly say that Spanish has irregular plurals unlike English, whose irregularities are often inconsistent. 
I'd like to add that Spanish is probably the most straightforward language in the Romance group, even minor Iberian languages seem slightly harder to me....