# How did the words "mataburros" and "tumbaburros" come to mean "dictionary"?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, acepciones, compuestos

[This recent question about irregular plurals](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/457/are-there-any-nouns-with-irregular-plurals-in-spanish) led me to a couple of odd and interesting words that apparently mean "dictionary" in at least one sense each:

- [*mataburros*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mataburros)
- [*tumbaburros*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tumbaburros)

The connection between dictionaries and donkeys and their knocking over or killing seems tenuous at best. Does anybody know if there's a story behind them?

As a bonus question, my dictionary says *mataburros* is rioplatense and Wiktionary says it also means *grille guard* or *bumper guard*. Whereas for *tumbaburros* my dictionary says it's Mexican and also means *bull bar*. Do these regional tags and other senses match what you know?

Comment: My 81 year old father who is from southern New Mexico tells me that there was a form of liquor (possibly homemade) that my mother's father drank circa 1950 called mataburro.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A una persona con pocos conocimientos se le dice coloquialmente "burro". Un "mataburros" es literalmente algo que elimina a los burros y de ahí que (en Argentina, por ejemplo) al diccionario se le diga "mataburros" pues ayuda a suprimir burros, es decir, personas sin conocimientos. Un caso similar sucede con "tumbaburros" que es otra de las maneras coloquiales (en México al menos) de referirse a un diccionario.

En cuanto al bono, mataburros con el significado de diccionario solo lo he escuchado en Argentina y tumbaburros, también con el significado de diccionario, solo se lo he escuchado a amigos mexicanos.

Comment: +1 en mi tierra se le llama amansa-burros

Comment: In Brazil, "pai dos burros" (father of the dumb) used to refer to the dictionary.  But I haven't heard that for a long time now.

Answer (score 11):

According to the RAE's dictionary, "*[mataburros](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=burro)*" means *dictionary* only in  Argentina, Costa Rica, Cuba, Honduras, Uruguay and Venezuela; "*[tumbaburros](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=burro)*", as you said, only in Mexico.

Since "burro" is also used to refer to ignorant/rude/uncivil people, the "mataburro" becomes an object that "kills" those kind of people.

Answer (score 3):

See hippietrail, the thing is that "*burro*" is used as a synonym to a person without education. That's why *mataburro* means *mata ignorantes* wich means (kill ignorance).

"*Mataburro*" actually is also used as bumper guard (Colombia AFAIK).

Comment: burro isn't a synonym, as much as a colloquialism.

Comment: I would say "is a word used in one sense to mean a person without education". Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation I received in Cuba is that when a turista is not fluent in Spanish and constantly uses their English/Spanish dictionary,  it so boring to them that it would be enough to kill a donkey.  Just my two cents.